# Transfer files between servers using php

Tags: php

```
Hello
I wrote a little code in php that enables me to download a file from one
 website to my own!
but there is a little problem here!
I can only Download files from my website that are less than 4MB:(
Now my question is that in what way I can Download special 
part of files from other websites!
like from 1st byte to 10th byte!

And second question is how to get file 
Information before starting Download!
(I want files size for downloading)
```

http://www.polarpengi.gigfa.com/code.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function downloadFileFromUrl($url, $dstFilepath) {
    $fr = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if($fr === false) {
        throw new Primage_Proxy_Storage_SourceNotFound($url);
    }
    $fw = fopen($dstFilepath, 'w');
    if($fw === false) {
        throw new Exception('Writing to file "' . $dstFilepath . '" failed');
    }

    $timeLimit = 1000;
    set_time_limit($timeLimit);
    $deadline = time() + 1000;

    while(!feof($fr)) {
        $bufferString = fread($fr, 10000);
        fwrite($fw, $bufferString);
        if($deadline - time() < 10) {
            fclose($fw);
            fclose($fr);
            unlink($dstFilepath);
            throw new Primage_Proxy_Storage_SourceNotFound($url);
        }
    }
    fclose($fw);
    fclose($fr);
}
```

Comment: how about using SFTP if the file is not accessible via URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a limit of how much bytes the curl operation will read using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,"1-2000"); //where 1-2000 range of downloaded bytes
```

however I don't think using curl to download a file is appropriate.
Use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead.

Comment: And why downloading a file via curl would be inappropriate? Command-line version of CURL is a perfect solution for downloading files, so why the library wouldn't? And why a function that is putting a file into *array* is better?